# Node.js: function "not defined" if declared as fat arrow

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to write a recursion within a closure. The recursive part is in a function. Here is the schema:

```
if (whatever) {
  doStuff: (x) => {
     if (x<10) doStuff(x+1);
  }

  doStuff(0);
}
```

And it doesn't work: `doStuff is not defined.` But this works:

```
if (whatever) {
  function doStuff(x) {
     if (x<10) doStuff(x+1);
  }

  doStuff(0);
}
```

I tried declaring the function in many ways, but it never works if it's declared as an arrow function. I wonder why?

Comment: `const doStuff = (x) => ...` and it'll work. Only use `:` when defining properties of objects

Comment: I'm surprised never to have seen this mistake before. You can *totally* see how the OP got there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have seen that question and similar ones, once in a while here, but it is nearly impossible to find them again.

Comment: @t.niese - It's a new one on me (well, or my aging memory is failing me). But yeah, I know what you mean about finding ones you've seen before. It's getting *seriously* "needle in haystack" around here. :-)

Comment: Yet another reason to default to *function declarations* for declaring functions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that outside an object initializer, this:

```
doStuff: (x) => {
   if (x<10) doStuff(x+1);
}
```

...is a [*label*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (`doStuff:`) followed by an arrow function expression creating a function that you never save or call, you just throw it away. It's not about the arrow function, you'd have the same problem if you used a traditional function expression:

```
doStuff: function(x) {    // Same problem, but with traditional function expression
   if (x<10) doStuff(x+1);
}
```

Instead, if you want it to be an arrow function, assign it to a variable or a constant:

```
const doStuff = (x) => {
   if (x<10) doStuff(x+1);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

The way used is not a correct way to define function. Just replace`:` with `=` and initialize **whatever** variable with any truthy value.

Below is your modified code.

```
 var whatever = true

 if (whatever) {
    var doStuff = (x) => {
         if (x<10) 
             return x + doStuff(x+1);
         return x
    }
    console.log(doStuff(0)) // 55
 }
```

Comment: You have never declared `doStuff`.

Comment: Wrong nonetheless. Don't count on browsers' error tolerance.

Comment: No-one has said that it doesn't work, but you still haven't declared `doStuff`. And it *won't* work in strict mode. http://rextester.com/TBID9202

Comment: That's correct, it will not work in strict mode. Let me modify the answer, http://rextester.com/BEY76292. Thanks.